# XSL:include not working at all

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, web

Here is my setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:include href="top.xsl"/>  
<xsl:template match="">
Content here - divs and such
</xsl:template>            
</xsl:transform>
```

Then this is the stylesheet that I am trying to include.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
Standard html file now, html, head,title,script,body etc.
```

Closes like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why won't the include work?

Edit: Here is the full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3432742335a8fd3c600f

Comment: "*Why won't the include work?*" How do you determine that it doesn't? Please post some **reproducible** code. `<xsl:template match="">` will cause a fatal error with or without include.

Comment: I've posted the full code now in the OP.

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal, but complete example (XML + XSLT) here.

Comment: If the github code really is the full code then another issue (despite of the mentioned error you should get because of the empty `match=""`) is that you're including `top.xsl` but the name of the file is `nav.xsl`, or is the file just missing there?

Comment: @matthias_h Oh damn, you're correct! I put the wrong file name. Regarding the match="", what should go into the quotations?

Comment: Normally I'd just say - whatever you want to match :) But as I just looked through your templates - it looks like you're just adding some divs at the end of the html, so I suggest you remove the `match=""`, add a `name="something"`, and, instead of applying templates at the end of the including template, just make a call there for this template - `<xsl:call-template name="something"/>`, as you can't have two templates matching the root node (only the later would be written). Or check if the answer just given by Tim C is working for you.

Comment: Thank you. The answer below works perfectly fine so I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `<xsl:apply-templates />` in your `nav.xsl` this will look for child nodes of the document node. As XML needs a single root element to be well-formed, you can replace your currently empty template match with this to match this root element

```
<xsl:template match="/*" >
```